# Button to change background color in all forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I only studied a bit of visual basic at school and I'm trying to do something on my own now, sorry if it's a dumb question.

I created a few buttons which change the background color using this:

```
Private Sub bgcblue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bgcblue.Click
        BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
    End Sub
```

Yet, I don't know how to make it change the color on other forms. That's the only one where you have the option to choose, so, if, for example, you chose blue, the following forms would have a blue background too.

The only way I can think of is writing in the beginning of each form an if clause stating that if that button was clicked on the previous form, then it should have that color, but that seems a lot of code... can anyone help? I'm sorry if you don't understand what I said or I said it incorrectly...

Comment: thats more like a User Option.  Save the color to My.Settings, then when each form loads read the value back in Form Load and apply it.

Comment: I agree to @Plutonix, although creating a global variable may do also, but still I prefer to .net My.Settings, its accessible on run time and in design time.

Answer (score 2):

> Create a public property in module which will be used by all forms to
>   set initial background color in there load event. when you set color
>   of this property change background color of all open forms

Property in Module

```
Module Module1
    Private m_FormBackgroundColor As Color
    Public Property FormBackgroundColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_FormBackgroundColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            m_FormBackgroundColor = value
            For Each Frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
                Frm.BackColor = m_FormBackgroundColor
            Next
        End Set
    End Property
End Module
```

set background color for each from in its load event

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.BackColor = FormBackgroundColor
    End Sub
End Class
```

on button click to set background color

```
Private Sub bgcblue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bgcblue.Click
    FormBackgroundColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set a global variable called `BackgroundColor` somewhere in a module, so it can be accessed by all forms.
When you click the button, you set the value of the variable. Either true falce, if you just toggle between two colours, or to the actual value of your new background colour
Then when you load a new form, have it set it's bakground colour from the value of the variable.

It's the simple option. There are more complicated ones...
I can elaborate a couple of other ways if you want, just let me know.

Comment: This is correct. Perhaps an example to further help the asker? 
I can edit one, with your permission.

Comment: Sure, that would be really useful indeed. I'm at work now, so can't knock one up, but if you can, please do :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was away for a few days. I understand that, but I haven't worked with modules yet, I tried to make it work but there's always something wrong with what I write. Could you write an example on how that would work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In VB, that's really easy.  You just have to reference your other form.  Instead of just saying `BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue` you reference that property by adding the form name...so `YourMainForm.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a module item from **Project--> add new item --> common items--> module**
write the code in the module

```
Module Module1
    Public Sub form_background(ByVal frm As Form)' pass current form as system.controls.form
        frm.BackColor = Color.Azure ' Set the back ground color as .Azure
    End Sub
End Module
```

Call the function in each page you are adding, like the following

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    form_background(Me)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the button click code, you could just do the following

```
Private Sub bgcblue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bgcblue.Click
    BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
    form1.Backcolor = Color.DeepskyBlue
    form2.Backcolor = Color.DeepSkyBlue 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To change **background colors** of all forms:

- Create a table to store color names.
- In a module, create a global variable and give it a value that is selected from the table using a combo to use more than one color.
- Call any form to load the variable and set the form background color properties to that variable.